# How to send List<double> to iOS in Flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

In my first foray into Objective C, I'm trying to send a list of numbers from flutter to iOS.

This is my dart code:

```
@override
  Future<void> setMix(int textureId, List<double> mix) {
    return _channel.invokeMethod<void>(
      'setMix',
      <String, dynamic>{
        'textureId': textureId,
        'mix': mix,
      },
    );
  }
```

and iOS:

```
if ([@"setMix" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        [player setMix:[argsMap[@"mix"] array]];
        result(nil);
        return;
    }
```

Sending the mix as a list of doubles (expecting an NSArray) results in the error:
`[NSNull array]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I've tried sending a list of num and a list of Strings, each with a similar error, although the documentation says it supports lists which get translated as NSArray.

I tried sending a list of doubles and accepting FlutterStandardTypedData, which seemed to work, but I couldn't iterate over it to get the data.

I've ended up sending a comma delineated string and converting it to an array in iOS. This works but I'm sure there's a better way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is type matching with swift: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec

Comment: Thank you. That document includes type matching for all platforms. But as my question stated, I've tried all of those but cannot get them to work